# Euclid's Algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I was reading Donald Knuth's Art of Computer Programming and it occurred to me that I should also code along while reading.

```
function Euclid(m,n){
  var greatestDivider = 0;
  if(m > n){
    for(var i = 1; i < m; i++){
      if(m % i === 0 && n % i === 0 && i !== 1){
        greatestDivider = i;
      }
    }
  }else {
    for(var j = 1; j < n; j++){
      if(m % j === 0 && n % j === 0 && j !== 1) {
        greatestDivider = j;
      }
    }
  }
 console.log('common divisor is : ' + greatestDivider);

}
Euclid(30,90);
```

Is it efficient to employ the algorithm in such a way ?

Comment: One comment in addition to le_m's answer, it might be quicker to count down and stop on the first match rather than counting up and testing every possible value.

Comment: @MarcRohloff Comments are for seeking clarification to the question, and may be deleted. Please put all suggestions for improvements in answers, even trivial ones.

Answer (score 3):

Let me recommend a few general improvements before addressing the efficiency:

**Naming:**

- Change `Euclid` to `gcd`:

  - Lower case initial letter for function names.
  - `gcd` is the common term for greatest common divisor, the Euclidean algorithm is just one possible implementation. And you are not implementing the Euclidean algorithm.
  - Rename the second loop iterator `j` to `i`. Iterator `j` usually indicates a nested loop where `i` is the outer and `j` the inner loop iterator.

**Design:**

- Don't log outputs within the `Euclid` function. Removing `console.log` makes it a [pure, side-effect free function](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15269/why-are-side-effects-considered-evil-in-functional-programming). Those are much easier to reason about.
- Remove the outer `if ... else` and get rid of the duplicate code by precomputing a common for-loop test-condition `var end = Math.min(m, n)`.
- It doesn't make sense to start the loop with `i = 1` and have a check `i !== 1` in the loop body. Either start with `i = 2` or better remove that check, as it causes `Euclid(2, 3)` to output `0` instead of `1`.
- Also, end the loop when `i <= m` instead of `i < m`. This guarantees that e.g. `Euclid(3, 3)` outputs `3` instead of `0`.

This is your code with above suggestions applied:

```
function gcd(m, n) {
  var result = 0;

  for (var i = 1, end = Math.min(m, n); i <= end; i++) {
    if (m % i === 0 && n % i === 0) {
      result = i;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

This implementation is pretty slow. The modulo operator has the [same performance penalty as the division operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977834/why-is-modulus-operator-slow). Also, your implementation only works with positive arguments.

This is the actual [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations) (division variant):

```
function gcd(a, b) {
  while (b !== 0) {
     var t = b; 
     b = a % b;
     a = t;
  }
  return a;
}
```

Comment: That's a beautiful code. Thanks for pointing out the problems. I should have used a temp value as well.

Comment: @Ozan Using a temporary `end` or `length` variable is a pretty common 'micro-optimization'. Some prefer to move this declaration out of the loop initializer. The advantage here is: You have only a single path of execution, which allows the compiler to detect and optimize 'hotspots' earlier. Also, the code is more DRY (don't repeat yourself).

Comment: You could also use the more explanatory `var end = Math.min(n, m)`

Comment: @MarcRohloff I agree, edited the answer. Thanks!

Comment: What really confuses me most of the time when I code in JavaScript is the fact that the arrow function resembles <= a lot and yet the other way around is >= but somehow I end up mixing >= with => when I use for loops.